# How to install Android 4.0 (API 14) in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

I didn't know, how to install Android 4.0 in my eclipse tool?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the SDK

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html

Then download the version you want in your case the 4.0 like this

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/adding-packages.html

You are developing on Eclipse so follow those steps to install the ADT plugin

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html

And then start coding :)

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/next.html

Answer (score 3):

Click on Android Sdk Manager in Eclipse . Now select the checkbox Android 4.0 and Click on Install Packages. Accept and Install.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please see my above question and screen shots for your reference.

Comment: What to do if we can not find that api list in our sdk..?

Answer (score 0):

click android sdk manager in eclipse check android 4.0 -- and click install you are done

Answer (score 0):

You open the SDK manager either by double click or by Eclipse and then you select Android 4.0 and install.

Instructions for the plugin can be found here: http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse go to:

> **Window > Android SDK Manager**

And now select the checkbox Android 4.1 and below hit on Install 6 packages

:)

Answer (score 0):

You have to update your ADT plug-in:
In Eclipse, select Help > Install New Software and then write ADT. After the update you will be able to see Android 4 and later.