# Error in adding an edit text in eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm building an Android app for a tablet. I'm trying to add an `EditText` in my graphical view in Eclipse but whenever I choose `EditText` from the widget and drop to the graphical view, the screen turn gray and i get this error

```
" Exception raised during rendering: java.lang.System.arraycopy([CI[CII)V
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log"
```

How to fix this problem?

Comment: Would http://stackoverflow.com/a/24473444/6309 help?

Comment: use android studio for better drag and drop option . Best way for eclipse is to create it with xml.

Comment: @VonC yes it will help full..

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In the new update come the 4.4W (Android Wear) and he doesnt support `EditText`, so the best and simple way to solve is deleting 4.4W.

Go to

> Window > Android SDK Manager > check Android 4.4W(API 20) > Delete
>   package

Maybe then you can't create a new project, so you back to SDK manager and download another version like 4.4.2(API 19).

It works for me, hope for you too.

Comment: No need to delete the API 20 package.

this problem happened on API 20 ( Android 4.4 W ) I recently have a problem with that but Problem will be solved by changing Android version to use for rendering level form API 20 ( Android 4.4 W ) to API 19 (Android 4.4.2) ( android icon in top right corner of graphical layout ) or update your SDK to Android L ( API 20 L preview )

Reference: Exception raised during rendering: java.lang.System.arraycopy

Answer (score 4):

Android W(atch) doesn't support Text Fields.

Lower the API level to <=19 and it should work.

This was mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/24473444/666208

Answer (score 0):

No need to delete the API 20 package.

this problem happened on API 20 ( Android 4.4 W ) I recently have a problem with that but Problem will be solved by changing Android version to use for rendering level form API 20 ( Android 4.4 W ) to API 19 (Android 4.4.2) ( android icon in top right corner of graphical layout ) or update your SDK to Android L ( API 20 L preview )

Reference: [Exception raised during rendering: java.lang.System.arraycopy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24451490/exception-raised-during-rendering-java-lang-system-arraycopy/24473444#24473444)