# Android: How to add a API exception?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, google-play-services, wear-os

I am developing a app containing **EditTexts** and I want to **support API 21 (Android L).**

But my app contains EditTexts and since *API 20 (4.4 Android KitKat Wear) doesn't support EditTexts*, how to **add an exception to API 20 and prevent Android Wear users from downloading** it from Play Store while still supporting API 21?

Comment: `EditText` is definitely available on API Level 20. They may not be available on Wear devices, but that is not tied to the API level.

Comment: @CommonsWare is right, and even if it weren't you can specify which devices are able to run your app in your manifest and/or in the developer console. Just throwing an exception when an unsuspecting user is running your app for the first time is pretty bad and can only leave one kind of impression: a bad one.

Comment: EditText is not available in API 20.

Comment: What makes you think that it isn't? And please explain to me this: Why would a class that has been in the Android framework from day one just suddenly be removed in API level 20? You are wrong.

Comment: API level 20 is for Android Wear devices not for normal android phones. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24592647/error-in-adding-an-edit-text-in-eclipse

Comment: Yes, smart watches don't support `EditTexts`, they are not designed for text input, but that has nothing to do with the phone itself, you can still have an `EditText` there. Are you asking about an android wear device or a phone?

Comment: To support API 21, I need to support API 20. I just don't want to support API 20.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean. You can't and there is no reason to do that anyway. See the answer of @CommonsWare.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But my app contains EditTexts and since API 20 (4.4 Android KitKat Wear) doesn't support EditTexts,

First, API Level 20 supports `EditText`. You can tell this by actually trying it. For example, I just took [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Basic), and not only does it compile fine with a build target of API Level 20, but it runs fine on an API Level 20 emulator. Issues, if any, are with the *hardware*, not the *API level*.

Second, Android Wear users cannot download apps on their Wear devices. They download apps for their phone, and those phone apps have a Wear app inside of them (as a raw resource) that is then loaded onto the Wear device. So long as you do not create a Wear app that uses an `EditText`, and then package that Wear app inside of another app for distribution, you are safe.

Comment: @MarkRenouf: "Wear devices have no keyboard support" -- I would imagine that is up to the manufacturer. Moreover, that does not change the fact that `EditText` is supported on API Level 20. Do not confuse a device (Wear) with an API level. For example, Google TV devices did not support the NDK; this did not mean that Android 3.1 did not support the NDK.

Comment: I understand -- And I wasn't clear about what he was asking. I thought he was claiming that Wear will support EditText in "L", which makes no sense. But in fact your answer was correct -- he didn't understand that a wear app was packaged distinctly different from a regular app, and not just directly installed from Play.