# Why is the EditText not showing in android?

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext

I am completely new to android. The EditText is not showing up in the graphical layout.

**xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:ems="10"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

There is also a little yellow underline after ''. When I put my mouse cursor on it, it says nothing. I couldn't find the answer I was looking for. The graphical layout looks less brighter than the original, and is as follows:
[image]

And no I haven't run the program yet. Plz.

Comment: Did you follow the exception message and check the error log? Also, you have the API target set to 20, is that on purpose?

Comment: Is this Eclipse or Android Studio? Are there any other files you created in the project? For example other layouts, fragments or activities which are problematic bring up this error.

Comment: what I did was just googled exact line of the error and guess what I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24451490/exception-raised-during-rendering-java-lang-system-arraycopy . please consider searching for problem before posting it here. it saves your and everyone else's time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution from the below link , this problem happened on API 20 ( Android 4.4 W ) I recently have a problem with that but Problem will be solved by changing Android version to use for rendering level form API 20 ( Android 4.4 W ) to API 19 (Android 4.4.2) ( android icon in top right corner of graphical layout ) or update your SDK to Android L ( API 20 L preview )

Ref : [Exception raised during rendering: java.lang.System.arraycopy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24451490/exception-raised-during-rendering-java-lang-system-arraycopy)

Comment: There's no need to duplicate an answer if you don't add anything to it. Just flag as a dupe

Comment: i added it as flag Dupe.. thanks .