# Error while adding text field in Emulator

Tags: android, xml, exception, android-emulator

Whenever I add any `TextView` in the XML file it shows me the error "Exception raised during rendering: java.lang.System.arraycopy([CI[CII)V".

What is the reasoning behind this?

This is the XML part where the above written error is being shown.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

Comment: It would benefit you to add your xml, at least the part where you're trying to ass a view

Comment: possible duplicate of [Exception raised during rendering: java.lang.System.arraycopy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24451490/exception-raised-during-rendering-java-lang-system-arraycopy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the "Android version to use when rendering layouts". Chose any version that does not have "W" at the end . Those versions are for wearable devices.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This problem happened on `API 20` (Android 4.4 W). Problem will be solved by changing Android version to use for rendering level `form API 20` (Android 4.4 W) to `API 19` (Android 4.4.2) (android icon in top right corner of graphical layout) or update your SDK to Android L (API 20 L preview)

[**Source of answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24451490/exception-raised-during-rendering-java-lang-system-arraycopy/24473444#24473444)

[image]