# how to see layout on graphical layout in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I make a simple demo in adroid .Actually I am beginner in android . I saw tutorial in which user able to see graphical  layout(wh) .But when I added some xml and run on emulator it look fine .But when I check on graphical layout it doesn't display any thing .is there any setting ? can you please how I am able to chek on graphical layout

[image]

Comment: follow this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24501042/android-app-in-eclipse-edit-text-not-showing-on-graphical-layout

Comment: You see Android Launcher(greencolor) symbol with 20 selected. Try selecting 19 or less?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem with the SDK API 20 (for wearables). You should be able to use SDK 19 or 21 and the layout will show up. You need to install one of these SDKs, then select it (button with android icon and "20").

See [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24451490/exception-raised-during-rendering-java-lang-system-arraycopy)