# Latest android studio update doesn't support percent layouts?

Tags: android, android-studio

Using the percent layout throws an exception in design view: Exception raised during rendering: android/support/percent/R$styleable or Exception raised during rendering: 8 ava.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 8
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.AarResourceClassGenerator.generateStyleable(AarResourceClassGenerator.java:210)

Worked before, I updated today: Android Studio 2.0 Build #AI 9321

Is there a way to rollback the update?

```
 <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">
 <ImageView
     app:layout_widthPercent="50%"
     app:layout_heightPercent="50%"
     app:layout_marginTopPercent="25%"
     app:layout_marginLeftPercent="25%"/>
 </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

api version should be specified as 23 because support version is 23.2.1

Comment: is it runtime exception or in xml viewer of Android Studio?

Comment: xml viewer aka "design view"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24451490/exception-raised-during-rendering-java-lang-system-arraycopy see this link

Comment: try changing api version in your design view to below 23

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Comment: Yes, I had to restart Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you are using latest version of the library.
2. Restart Android Studio.
3. Build your project.

Problem is gone!